# How to access variables from command in a view?

Tags: laravel

Good evening community.
I'm executing a command on terminal, I want to access `$per` variable in my mail view and it is giving me an error that it can't recognize the `$per` variable.

This is the command code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\pamatrizinfoperio;
use App\Periodicidad;
use App\Mail\SendMailable;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class EnvAlert extends Command
{
      //public $periodos;
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'Send:Alert';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Send Emails';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {

 $pers = Periodicidad::select('paperiodicidad.des','pamatrizinfoperio.des', 'pamatrizinfoperio.codpar')
                ->join('pamatrizinfoperio', 'pamatrizinfoperio.cod_paperiodicidad', '=', 'paperiodicidad.cod')
              ->where('pamatrizinfoperio.read_at', '=', 0)
               ->get();

        $data = array('name' => "Alert" , );
    Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message) {

        $message ->from('coop@gmail.com', 'ALERT');
        $message ->to('coop@gmail.com')->subject('Alert');
    });
    return "The alert was send";
    }
}
```

And this is the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Message Send</title>
</head>
<body>
        <ul class="list-group">

            @foreach($pers as $per)
            <li class="list-group-item">
            {{$per->des}}
            {{$per->des}}

   </li>
@endforeach 


@endforeach
        </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the same variable in other views, with the same query in the code and it works normally only that I declare them in the controller, but in this case I do not know why it does not work for me, I hope you can help me, any data you need I will provide. Sorry if my English is a little bad, I would appreciate a lot to help me in this, because as you will notice the function of the system so to speak, it is only to send emails informing about a job and the time to deliver it. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing variable named `$data` to the mail and you are accessing a different variable in the mail view

In you case, Your handle function should be like this

```
public function handle(){
    $pers = Periodicidad::select('paperiodicidad.des','pamatrizinfoperio.des', 'pamatrizinfoperio.codpar')
                        ->join('pamatrizinfoperio', 'pamatrizinfoperio.cod_paperiodicidad', '=', 'paperiodicidad.cod')
                        ->where('pamatrizinfoperio.read_at', '=', 0)
                        ->get();

    $data = ['name' => 'Alert',
            'pers' => $pers];

    Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message) {
        $message ->from('coop@gmail.com', 'ALERT');
        $message ->to('coop@gmail.com')->subject('Alert');
    });
    return "The alert was send";
}
```

Then you will be able to access the `$pers` in your mail view, 
I hope it helped you :)